# Use single definition file thoughout all packages and perl scripts

Tags: perl

I have a text file which has the physical paths (location/definitions) of multiple files. I simply used "reqiure" to include this text files and then used the variables declared there. But, now I am trying to make my code modular (it wasn't this far). What is the best way to go around this.

I made separate packages and defined subroutines there. I need the same definition file throughout all the packages and the perl files. I am able to use the variables only one way, either in the modules declaration or in the perl script which call the subroutines in these modules.

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you put your Paths into another "config.pm"-module? There, you could use a hash `%Data = ( HOME => '/home', WORK => '/work' );` Then, you could just 'use' this module everywhere and access the vars `$stuff = $Data{HOME}` etc ...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small use case that might be helpful. You have
 - one module (.pm) with your data needed everywhere
 - one module (.pm) containing subroutines
 - one main program (.pl)

The main program (program.pl):

```
 use strict;
 use warnings;

 use Data;
 printf "%s\n%s\n", $Path->{HOME}, $Path->{WORK};

 use MyModule; # uses Data
 printf mymoduleproc();
```

The module with subroutines (MyModule.pm):

```
 package MyModule;
 use strict;
 use warnings;
 use base 'Exporter';
 our @EXPORT = qw(mymoduleproc);

 use Data;
 sub mymoduleproc {
    return "MyModule => $Data::Path->{HOME}, $Data::Path->{WORK}" 
 }
 1;
```

The module with your (path) config data (Data.pm):

```
 package Data;
 use strict;
 use warnings;
 use base 'Exporter';
 our @EXPORT = qw($Path);

 our $Path =  { HOME => '/home', WORK => '/work'};
 1;
```

This is a very simple construct but should lead you further up the road.
Also, please [read here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_modules.htm).

rbo